# I'm trying to install create-react-app, however its not working properly. Can someone please assist?

Tags: reactjs, npm

[[image]]

//This is what I get when trying to install create react app globally

Comment: Typo in the Command name . "create-react-app" npm install create-react-app -g

Answer (score 1):

1. Seems you have typo in create-react-app.
2. Also have you tried with npx? Here is the step by step link to setup: https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html

Please note that npx comes with npm installation. So, please make sure you have installed Node >= 8.10 and npm >= 5.6 on your machine before try npx.

Steps to confirm the node and npm versions (assuming you are on MacOS):

1. Open Terminal and run the command: npm --version (it should have the version >=5.6)
2. Then run the command node --version (again it should have the version >=8.10).

Once you confirmed the above are installed properly on your Mac then you can run the following commands to get started with React:
npx create-react-app

Enjoy Learning React!

Answer (score 0):

You made a typing mistake `create-reacr` in your command

Answer (score 0):

**In node older versions used**

npm install -g create-react-app

create-react-app myapp // *myapp is app name.*

**In node latest version we can use**

npx create-react-app